# Reshaping DataFrame from long to wide by timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
                   time       user
2019-10-01 00:00:05 UTC          1
2019-10-01 00:00:22 UTC          1
2019-10-01 00:00:23 UTC          2
2019-10-01 00:00:35 UTC          2
```

It also has a number of other columns with information about the user. I would like to assign to each row the past information/rows for that user. The result should look like this:

```
                   time       user                  time_past_1
2019-10-01 00:00:05 UTC          1                           NA
2019-10-01 00:00:22 UTC          1      2019-10-01 00:00:05 UTC
2019-10-01 00:00:23 UTC          2                           NA
2019-10-01 00:00:35 UTC          2      2019-10-01 00:00:23 UTC
```

Ideally, the method should work for any number of past information/rows I wish to assign. In the example above, only one was assigned.

Looping through each row seems the most obvious but the DataFrame is large and so this will take a while. I've looked into pivot tables and long_to_wide, but I don't see how to make these work for this application.

Comment: What is the logic behind `time_past_1`? Judging by the name I'd say it's time passed since 1st row of the group (time difference between current row and 1st of the current group), but the value appears just the same as the 1st of each group.

Comment: `df['time_past_1'] = df.groupby('user')['time'].shift()`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `df.groupby().shift(n)`. First, let's set up the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [datetime(2019, 10, 1, 0, 0, 5), datetime(2019, 10, 1, 0, 0, 22),
                            datetime(2019, 10, 1, 0, 0, 23), datetime(2019, 10, 1, 0, 0, 35)],
                   'user': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'other': ['tick', 'tock', 'on the', 'clock']})
```

Now we'll do the groupby. `.shift(1)` on a column or whole dataframe will give you the previous value (or further back if you give a number greater than 1). Using it with groupby will do the same thing within each group, so we'll have a null value at the start of each group like your example:

```
new_cols = df.groupby('user').shift(n)
```

If we print that out you'll see the desired new columns, but not the original ones:

```
>>> print(new_cols)
                 time   other
0                 NaT     NaN
1 2019-10-01 00:00:05    tick
2                 NaT     NaN
3 2019-10-01 00:00:23  on the
```

So we'll use `df.join` to put the pieces together. By default it will join on the index of both dataframes, so we don't need to specify which columns to join on (since `groupby().shift()` gives us something with the same index as the original dataframe)

```
df = df.join(new_cols, rsuffix = "_1")
```

and the final result:

```
>>> df
                 time  user   other              time_1 other_1
0 2019-10-01 00:00:05     1    tick                 NaT     NaN
1 2019-10-01 00:00:22     1    tock 2019-10-01 00:00:05    tick
2 2019-10-01 00:00:23     2  on the                 NaT     NaN
3 2019-10-01 00:00:35     2   clock 2019-10-01 00:00:23  on the
```

Notice that this did every column except `'user'`, since that's what we used as the group index. This is the default behavior, but if you only want specific columns you can slice the groupby like this:

```
new_cols = df.groupby('user')[list_of_col_names].shift(n)
```

Also if you want to be really slick we can collapse this into one line rather than creating a `new_cols` variable like so:

```
df = df.join(df.groupby('user').shift(1), rsuffix = "_1")
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If I understand this correctly, shift will simply look for rows with a smaller row index. So, since I want to assign "past rows" as determined by the time column, I should first sort the dataframe by user and time. Then groupby and shift will give me the desired result.

Comment: Correct, this solution assumes that the dataframe is already sorted chronologically.